# How is it specific use UIDocumentPickerViewController in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Have this code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var d1: [String: Any]? = nil
    var res: ValidationResult?
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.jpeg, .png])
    documentPicker.delegate = self // <----- HERE
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

raise: `Expected declaration`

Why? What is wrong?

Also how can I start to show document view controller? How to get a reference to a viewcontroller?

Unfortunatelly this crashes:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            documentPicker.present(documentPicker, animated: true)
            
        }){ Text("Load JSON schema").padding() }
```

---

I found this for document handling: https://maheshsai252.medium.com/document-handling-in-swiftui-664cf050c724

Strange it does not have `body` like this:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the UIDocumentPickerViewController is only available for UIKit.
So you need to create (or better wrap it inside) a UIViewControllerRepresentable in order to use it in SwiftUI. That is what the ProjectDocumentPicker is doing:

[ProjectDokumentPicker](https://github.com/maheshsai252/SwiftUIDocumentsDemo/blob/main/Shared/Views/ProjectDocumentPicker.swift)

You then need to present this ProjectDocumentPicker as a sheet and open it e.g. via button click.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showDocumentPicker = false
    @StateObject var reportsVM: ProjectReportViewModel
    @State var added = false
    @State var inCloud = false

        var body: some View {
            Button("Open file") {
                self.showDocumentPicker = true
            }.sheet(
                isPresented: self.$showDocumentPicker,
                content: { ProjectDocumentPicker(reportsViewModel: reportsVM, added: $added, iniCloud: $inCloud) }
            )
        }
    }
```